# Постоянно возвращается http_response_code(200). Recaptcha, Ajax, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

Делаю обработку рекапчи средствами PHP, AJAX. Независимо от условий, возвращается код 200. Хотя условие с ошибкой, которое должно вернуть код 400 срабатывает. В связи с этим не работает корректная проверка формы. Пробовал дебажить, работает корректно, заходит в те места, в которые нужно, но по итогу все равно 200. Звонил в поддержку хостинга, думал нужно устанавливать какие-то PHP модули. PHP особо не знаю, впервые столкнулся в таком режиме. Отправка данных происходит только при выполненных условиях (заполнены все поля и капча чекнута, почему возвращается 200 - понять не могу)

HTML

```
<form class="form" method="post">

                    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Biotech">
                    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="sales@biotech.org.ua">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Контактные данные пользователя"> -->
                    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Имя и фамилия" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input id="email" type="text" name="E-mail" pattern="^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон">
                    </div>



                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdxczcUAAAAAKsbbef_VQgblw-khfd-S0RCL0Vq" style=""></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-button" value="Отправить">


                </form>

                <div id="output"></div>
```

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#submit-button').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var contactForm = $('.form');
                var formData = contactForm.serialize();

                console.log(formData);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "mailer.php",
                    data: formData
                })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        console.log("success");
                        $('#output').html(data.responseText);
                    })
                    .fail(function (data) {
                        console.log("error");
                        $('#output').html(data.responseText);

                    })
                    .always(function () {
                        console.log("complete");
                    });
                ;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    var_dump($_REQUEST);

    $name = trim($_POST["Name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["E-mail"]);
    $phone = trim($_POST["Phone"]);

    $captcha = '';

    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }

    $captcha = isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) ? $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] : "";

    if (empty ($captcha) ) {

        echo "check captcha";
        http_response_code(400);
        exit;

    }
    $recipient = "vladknure@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Пользователь c Biotech.org.ua.";

    $email_content = "Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Phone: $phone";

    $email_headers = "From: website";

    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LdxczcUAAAAAMeDD8JwV8JkjAGKDhghdyjGK2vK&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $decoded_response = json_decode($response);
    if ($decoded_response->success) {
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "all is okay";
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "you are spammer";
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery, recaptcha api - все подключено, сюда просто не копировал. 
Возвращается постоянно "success", то есть попадает только в done. 
Прикрепляю скриншоты [image: возвращается код 200. т.е. всё окей]
[image: хотя срабатывает условие и должно вернуть 400]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При помощи [Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman)
проблема была решена:

необходимо вместо http_response_code() вызывать `header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');` или `header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');` или `header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');` в таком случае будет возвращаться то, что нужно

Answer (score 3):

Сначала сервер должен отправлять заголовки(ок)

```
http_response_code(400);
```

И только после заголовков можно отправлять тело ответа

```
echo "check captcha";
```

Про http-протокол https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Comment: исправил - ничего не поменялось

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, кеш браузера почистите.

Comment: я запускаю это локально на локалхосте, на хостинг перезагрузил тоже - ничего не поменялось. ответ то приходит, но код 200 как на скриншоте

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, при других ситуациях (`echo "all is okay";` и `echo "you are spammer";`) какие коды ответа приходят?

Comment: всегда 200 и ОК, как на скриншоте..искренне понять почему не могу. я уже принудительно бросал 400, но все равно

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, `var_dump(http_response_code(400));` Что придет в ответ `true` или `false`? У вас еще файл может быть в кодировке UTF-8 with BOM и заголовок файла сбивает вывод. Или еще где вывод в браузер идет до установки заголовков.

Comment: int(400) приходит.

Comment: при повторной отправке правильно заполненной формы приходит "you are spammer" , но код все равно 200....

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, пробуйте использовать `header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');`, `header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');`, `header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');` вместо `http_response_code()`.

Comment: @VladTeryoshin при повторном заполнении формы вы перезагружаете страницу? если нет - конечно придет сообщение "you are spammer" так как рекапча не даст добро, так как это одноразовое действие и необходимо программно или физически перегрузить рекапчу.

Comment: @Jean-Claude,все получилось, как подсказали в предыдущем комментарии.